# How to get status of remote windows service

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to get status of a remote windows service. I use code like this, but nothing happens. Labels have not get any value. Help my please!

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Password = "password";
options.Username = "username";
options.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\computer_name\\root\\cimv2", options);
scope.Connect();

ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("service_name", "computer_name");
label1.Text = sc.ServiceName;
label2.Text = sc.Status.ToString();
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does the account you are running under have enough permissions on the remote machine?

Comment: I don't get any errors and account have enough permissions.

Comment: I drew attention to the fact that the code is executed only to this line line scope.Connect();. The following code is not executed. Why is that?

Comment: What happens when you run this code under debugger and put a breakpoint on the next line (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController) ? I have tried your code on my box and it works fine.

Comment: I'm very surprised that code work fine. It's very strange. Do you get status of service from remote computer or local. When I'm putting the breakpoint on the next line nothing to happening. The breakpoint did not fire. BUT! If I'm using local machine name code work fine, it's true.